# Auto login get status from webbrowser control

Tags: c#, authentication, browser

I'm trying to log in from my program to another website.
This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill steam username & password");
        }
        else
        {
            browser.Navigate("WEBSITE");
            browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_Login);
        }
    }

    void browser_Login(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        browser.Document.GetElementById("AccountName").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
        browser.Document.GetElementById("Password").SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
        browser.Document.GetElementById("Login").InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

But I want to receive the status if the log in failed or succeeded. How can i do this ?

Comment: Are you attempting to get users to give you their Steam username/password? Because that is a.) Against Valve's Terms of Service and b.) Going to trigger a SteamGuard check against their user account if you attempt to log into their account from a computer they have never been on before.

Comment: Nope, i`m trying to make a auto login program for a website that has login only trough steam community. Is just a program for more easy managing.

Comment: In that case, you need to use the Valve OpenID to log in through their service. They have a recommended number of [C# libraries](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/) to use.

Comment: I'll look forward to it